# Lie algebras in braided monoidal categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, lie-algebras, operads

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a **braided** (not necessarily symmetric) monoidal category. Then we can define what monoids and commutative monoids in $\mathcal{C}$ are. What is the correct definition of a Lie algebra in $\mathcal{C}$? I saw many different ones, none of them focusing on the for me important aspect, which is Koszul duality (in the sense of [GinzburgKapranov](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.1228.pdf)). So for $V \in \mathcal{C}$, I want $Comm(V) \cong T(V)/L(V)^{+}$ for the corresponding free objects (if they exist). I'm not an expert with operads, so I think I first need to understand how to define an operad in a braided monoidal category. I would be very thankful for some literature about that.

Comment: One keyword is "braided operads" which are to braided monoidal categories what operads and nonsymmetric operads are to symmetric monoidal and monoidal categories respectively.

Comment: Can you really reasonably define commutative algebras in braided monoidal categories?

Comment: @PhilTosteson maybe I'm misunderstanding you but non-symmetric operads only make sense in symmetric monoidal categories, and similarly for braided operads.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Don't you think that $\mu \circ c = \mu$ is a reasonable axiom?

Comment: @FernandoMuro  I think at least in the tensor category community its well-established (see for example [EGNO - Tensor categories])

Comment: @BipolarMinds not sure, you could replace $c$ with $c^{-1}$ and you would get a different definition, right?

Comment: @FernandoMuro no, $\mu \circ c=\mu$ iff $\mu \circ c^{-1}=\mu$

Comment: @Fernando I mean that algebras over a nonsymmetric operad make sense in any monoidal category.

Comment: @BipolarMinds fair enough XD

Comment: @PhilTosteson over a non-symmetric operad in the category of sets, yes. I meant you can't define operads in a non-symmetric monoidal category. Not even non-symmetric operads.

Comment: @FernandoMuro for non-symmetric operads, monoidal is enough

Comment: @BipolarMinds No, even the definition of non-sym operad uses the commutativity constraint.

Comment: @FernandoMuro see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad#In_other_categories, to give just one reference

Comment: @BipolarMinds that's actually only a short (and wrong) comment, one of many in that source.

Comment: @FernandoMuro oops, thanks for pointing that out, I see it now..

Comment: I think that most people trying to work with this kind of thing say that in the braided case one has a PROP, not an operad, see for example top of p.17 in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9303148